# ncurses in the background?

Tags: c++, ncurses

Why ncurses doesn't work in the background?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    while (true) {
        time_t seconds = time(nullptr);
        tm* timeinfo = localtime(&seconds);
        if (timeinfo->tm_hour >= 23 || timeinfo->tm_hour <= 3) {
            unsigned wait = 15 * 60;

            initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();
            printw("Go to bed, pls)\n");
            printw("Press enter:");
            int ch = getch();
            while (ch == 410) {
                ch = getch();
            }
            endwin();

            sleep(wait);
            continue;
        }
        unsigned wait = (23 - timeinfo->tm_hour) * 3600 - (60 - timeinfo->tm_min) * 60 - timeinfo->tm_sec;
        sleep(wait);
    }
}
```

But when I run this code in the background (./a.out &) I can't see ncurses window. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: To display a program properly, ncurses needs to be the only program outputting text to the terminal.  If you put it in the background, then your foreground interactions are going to be interfering with cursor placement, scrolling, font colour choices etc..  Just not a good idea....

Comment: It's probably waiting for input, not able to get that because it's in the background.  The output will happen when input is ready...

Comment: Try running `vi` in the background. Does it work? Should it work? *How* should it work?